# How to ignore commas within a CSV file being read by bash script

Tags: bash, csv

I have some fields that can separate the fields using the comma as delimiter, but some values actually contain commas, such as ""California , CA"" These values are surrounded by quotes to indicate the characters within should be treated as part of the field, but I don't know how to parse it to take this into same values.How to Ignore the comma(,) between string

Answer (score 2):

Use `FPAT` if your `awk` supports, its an `awk`s built-in variable to define the regex for fields rather than the delimiters. ITs like a complement to `FS` which is also `awk`s builtin variable.

Example:

```
echo 'hey there,ola,"Nice, command",ola' |awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' '{print $1}'
hey there
echo 'hey there,ola,"Nice, command",ola' |awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' '{print $2}'
ola
echo 'hey there,ola,"Nice, command",ola' |awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' '{print $3}'
"Nice, command"
echo 'hey there,ola,"Nice, command",ola' |awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' '{print $4}'
ola
```

Comment: why we need to make particular columns

Comment: @Manee, we'd hope for you to post sample data and expected output. Otherwise it's a guessing game that we usually can't win.

Comment: @manee because you would have to make awk aware of either field separator or field it self. Here field separator (comma) is going to play well as your field themselves contains comma in it.